# "Feel like at home"

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs

> Feel like at home.

Is it correct or must it be "***feel at home***"?

It is in a Euro 2012 commercial, however some experts say it's not correct.

Comment: _Feel like at home_ is grammatically wrong, and unlike  [_Winstons taste good like a cigarette should_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winston_tastes_good_like_a_cigarette_should#Grammar_controversy) it doesn't even sound good.  Please tell us more about what the phrase is supposed to mean. It's not clear that _feel at home_ is right either.

Comment: Hmmm I didn't know that a native speaker could have problems understanding it. It sounds so obvious for me: Feel (in Poland) in the same comfortable/happy way as in your own home. How can it be difficult to understand?

Answer (score 10):

I suspect *feel like at home* is a bad translation from some Polish phrase ([this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ayvr3ajfVH4) looks to be OP's "euro 2012 commercial", and it contains no English apart from having that title for the Youtube video).

I don't understand Polish anyway, but it's not obvious to me what a reference to *home* could mean in this context. Common idiomatic turns of phrase (*definitely* nothing to do with Euro 2012) are...

> [make yourself at home](http://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Idioms/M/make_yourself_at_home_716.htm) *- to relax and feel comfortable in someone else's home*.
>
> [feel at home [with something]](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/home) *- to have competence and familiarity with something.*

That second usage is normally "figurative". You can say you "feel at home with accounting software", for example, even if you only ever use it in the office. The point is you understand it, and are competent and familiar with using it.

---

EDIT: It seems my original link to "euro 2012 commercial" above is now dead. But [here's another one](http://www.newpolandexpress.pl/polish_news_story-4395-feel_like_at_home.php) which makes it clear that whatever Polish Sports Minister Joanna Mucha might say, the usage is probably best classified as a "glaring error".

Answer (score 3):

What they were looking for was "Make yourself at home!", i.e. the *imperative* mood, as in the Polish "Poczuj się jak w domu", which is a shorter way of saying "Proszę się czuć jak u siebie w domu".

In coming up with a literal translation of "Poczuj się jak w domu" they produced pure Ponglish.

http://octotext.com/index124.html

Comment: to a non -English speaker "Make oneself at home!" sounds odd , probably the same way the "feel like at home" sounds weird to those for whom English is a mother tongue. There's one more version that could be used - "Home form home"

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is "Feel like you do at home" -- a sentence with a slightly different sense then "Feel at home."

"Fell at home" can sometimes simply mean "be comfortable with"; "feel like you do at home" can never mean this.

For example, "I feel at home doing calculus" is natural English for "I am comforable doing calculus"; "I feel like I do at home doing calculus" would be very wrong.  However, you might say "Doing calculus here, I feel like I do at home" which would mean "It feels the same to do calculus here as at home."

Answer (score 0):

There's one more version that could be used - **"Home from home"**
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/home-from-home